# Building ruby version 2.6.10 with openssl v3 fails

Tags: ruby, openssl

I need to stay with ruby version 2.6.10 and my base OS is CentOS 6. I wonder if I can build this version of ruby with openssl v3? This is the ruby branch I am building from: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/v2_6_10

This is the error I am getting when compiling ruby 2.6.10 with openssl v3:

```
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0498806Z ossl_pkey_rsa.c:872:1: warning: 'RSA_set0_crt_params' is deprecated: Since       OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0499056Z In file included from /usr/local_ssl_3.0.0/include/openssl/x509.h:36:0,
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0499267Z                  from /usr/local_ssl_3.0.0/include/openssl/x509v3.h:25,
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0499451Z                  from ossl.h:23,
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0499626Z                  from ossl_pkey_rsa.c:10:
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0499829Z /usr/local_ssl_3.0.0/include/openssl/rsa.h:209:27: note: declared here
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0500092Z  OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 int RSA_set0_crt_params(RSA *r,
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0500279Z                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0535494Z In file included from ../.././include/ruby.h:33:0,
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0536068Z                  from ossl.h:16,
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0536408Z                  from ossl_pkey_rsa.c:10:
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0536922Z ossl_pkey_rsa.c: In function 'Init_ossl_rsa':
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0537392Z ossl_pkey_rsa.c:877:58: error: 'RSA_SSLV23_PADDING' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'RSA_NO_PADDING'?
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0537854Z  #define DefRSAConst(x) rb_define_const(cRSA, #x, INT2NUM(RSA_##x))
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0538062Z                                                           ^
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0538545Z ../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:261:33: note: in definition of macro 'RB_INT2FIX'
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0538956Z  #define RB_INT2FIX(i) (((VALUE)(i))<<1 | RUBY_FIXNUM_FLAG)
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0539289Z                                  ^
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0539750Z ../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1594:20: note: in expansion of macro 'RB_INT2NUM'
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0540018Z  #define INT2NUM(x) RB_INT2NUM(x)
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0540188Z                     ^~~~~~~~~~
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0540448Z ossl_pkey_rsa.c:877:50: note: in expansion of macro 'INT2NUM'
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0540671Z  #define DefRSAConst(x) rb_define_const(cRSA, #x, INT2NUM(RSA_##x))
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0540857Z                                                   ^~~~~~~
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0541109Z ossl_pkey_rsa.c:942:5: note: in expansion of macro 'DefRSAConst'
2023-07-11T04:27:11.0541310Z      DefRSAConst(SSLV23_PADDING);
```

I have built openssl v3 following :

```
git clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git openssl-3.0.0
cd openssl-3.0.0
git checkout openssl-3.0.0
export PATH=/usr/local_perl_5_24_1/bin:$PATH
./config --prefix=/usr/local_ssl_3.0.0 shared -no-ssl2 -no-ec -no-ec2m -no-ecdh
make depend
make
sudo make install_sw
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to get ruby built with openssl v3?

Compile ruby 2.6.10 with openssl v3.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 2.6 and all other Ruby versions prior Ruby 3.1 are not compatible with OpenSSL 3. When you need to run Ruby 2.6 then you need to downgrade to OpenSSL 1.0 or 1.1.

But because Ruby 2.6 reached end-of-life more than a year ago and doesn't get any security updates or bug fixes anymore. I highly recommend updating to an up-to-date Ruby version like 3.1 or 3.2 anyway.

Quote from the [Ruby bug tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/18658#note-18):

> > Status wurde von *Assigned* zu *Rejected* geändert
>
> We decided to not backport openssl-3.x gem into `ruby_2_7` and `ruby_3_0` branches. Because it affects with OpenSSL 1.0.x.
>
> Unfortunately, the users should upgrade their ruby version to 3.1+ before upgrading their OS version.

Comment: Thank you. We can upgrade ruby but we need to continue supporting openssl v1.0.* and openssl v1.1.* versions, will ruby 3.1+ compile with older versions of openssl?

Comment: Even if Ruby 3.1 worked with OpenSSL 1.1 that would still not be recommended. I would compile Ruby up to 3.0.x against OpenSSL 1.1 and when upgrading to Ruby 3.1 I would start compiling against OpenSSL 3. OpenSSL 1.0.2 is unsupported already, and support for OpenSSL 1.1.1 will end in two months. There is really no point in using an unsupported version of a cryptography and security related tool.